# I want to verify there are no broken links on the page using Capybara and rspec

Tags: rspec, capybara, broken-links

I'm using the below code to verify there are no broken links on the page using RSpec and capybara.

Then("I expect not to have broken links on the homepage") do

```rb
allinks = page.all('a')
allinks.each do |link|
  get link[:href]
  expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)
end
```

I'm confused with the code on Line no. 4 and 5. I'm trying to use the rack-test method 'get' to check the links without redirecting to the links.
The code is not throwing any error and getting passed even if the response code is changed from 200 to 400.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's happening with Capybara when you do that (I haven't used it for long)
I suspect `page` is the page that you're currently "in", probably memorized.

I'd suggest you try fetching the URL separately using, for example [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/basic.rb)

```
response = HTTParty.get(link[:href])
expect(response.code).to eq(200)
```

There might be issues with relative href attributes, like

```html
<a href="/home">I skipped domain</a>
```

But that's out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to check if all your pages are not broken, i.e if they respond with a correct status code (200) from a GET request?

I wrote this test for this. You can just pretty-much copy paste it for any Rails 5 application.

```rb
describe Rails.application.routes do
  describe '#get', type: :request do
    # This gets rails routes
    let(:routes_info) { described_class.routes }
    # this select GET routes
    let(:routes_get) { routes_info.select { |r| r.verb == 'GET' } }
    let!(:user) { create(:user) }

    specify 'GET routes returns 200, 301 or 302 code' do
      routes_get.each do |route|
        # parsing routes to a correct uri format
        route = route.path.spec.to_s.gsub(/\(.:format\)*$/, '')

        # route_with_params will replace ':security_token' with a test security token
        get route_with_params(route, user)
        expect(response.status).to eq(200).or eq(301).or eq(302)
      end
    end

    def route_with_params(route, user)
      route.gsub!(':security_token', user.security_token)
    end
  end
end
```

An added complexity here is that some GET pages require a user security token, so I had to create one for the test.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using rails application in my project so I'm not sure if this will still work.